# What is the major difference between maven `-f` and `-pl` parameters?

Tags: maven

When executing `mvn test -f file-directory` and `mvn test -pl project`.
What is the difference in internal execution of the both ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From `mvn -help`

```
 -f,--file <arg>                        Force the use of an alternate POM
                                        file.

 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
```

Example Usage:

- `-f`

  - If you want to build a Maven project but you are running Maven from a directory other than the directory which contains the pom.xml for that project.
  - If (for some reason) your POM file is not named pom.xml
- `-pl`

  - If you want to build a Maven build focussing on a sub set of the parent project's sub modules
  - If you want to resume a multiple module Maven build from the point at which a previous build failed

Given this project structure ...

```
+- tools
| |
| +- build
| |
+- projects
| |
| +- parent
|    |
|    +- pom.xml
|  
| +- childA
|    |
|    +- pom.xml
| +- childB
|    |
|    +- pom.xml
```

You could ...

- Build the `parent` project from the `tools/build` directory by using `-f` e.g.

  - `cd tools/build; mvn -f ../../projects/parent/pom.xml`
- Build only the childA sub module from the `tools/build` directory by using `-f` and `-pl` e.g.

  - `cd tools/build; mvn -f ../../projects/parent/pom.xml -pl parent:childA`
- Build only the childB sub module from the `parent` directory by using `-pl` e.g.

  - `cd projects/parent; mvn -pl parent:childB`